# Poner parte del título de un alertDialog en color

Tags: android, alertdialog

Estoy intentando poner parte del título que le he dado a un `alertDialog` en rojo, pero no consigo encontrar la solución sin tener que hacerlo a través de un `alertDialog` personalizado. Quería utilizar alguna función similar a lo que se habla en este post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under

Este es mi código:

```
dialogo.setTitle("¡"+listaBC.get(arg2).getFragilidad()+" !\n"+"¿Ha seguido esta recomendación?");
```

... y quiero que aparezca el rojo solamente el valor que rescato de la variable `listaBC.get(arg2).getFragilidad()`.

Comment: Por que no quieres que sea custom? Un layout especifico?

Comment: Parece un poco más enrevesado,  aunque voy a buscar en algún lado gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes definir un `style` para hacer este cambio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AlertColorRed" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Y luego

```
AlertDialog.Builder my_alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertColorRed));
```